# php function not extracting all images from directory

Tags: php

my code is not extracting all of the files inside the directory and i donde  know why, i dont have any extension  restrictions or anything, ok so this is my code  what am i doing wrong?  there are 24 images  with jpg and png extensions  and only  13 are detected when i `print_r($arr)`
:

```
<?php
function loadimages($dir) {     
    if(substr($dir, -1) != "/") $dir .= "/";
    $rootdir = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];
    $fulldir = $rootdir."/".$dir;
    $dir = opendir($fulldir);   
    $arr =  array();
    while(readdir($dir)) {              
        $arr[] = readdir($dir);
    }   
    echo  "<h1>".count($arr). "</h1><br />";
    foreach($arr as $img) {
        echo "<img src='/pages/course-images/{$img}' />";
    }
}   
loadimages("pages/course-images");
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `glob()` instead.

```
$images = glob('*.{png,jpg}', GLOB_BRACE);
print_r($images);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

It doesn't work because `while(readdir($dir))`, then you read one value and skips one step forward to the next file. The correct way would be this, and it's explaind in the manual.

```
while(false !== ($entry = readdir($dir))) {
      $arr[] =  $entry;
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php

But glob is better, now it only returns images.

Comment: ok thanks this works,  but i would really like to understand why readdir()   doesnt  work.